# CircleCI - Tags on default branch don't work

Tags: circleci

I want to have the following workflow:

1. master branch is connected to *dev* environment (every commit will trigger the workflow)
2. RC.X **on master** will deploy to *staging* environment

I'm trying the config.yml below, but when I tag a commit after it's pushed, it doesn't trigger.
Did anyone succeed doing this configuration?

config.yml:

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  build:
    jobs:
      - build:
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /RC.*/
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - install
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /RC.*/
            branches:
              only: /master/
```